# How to switch tabs with SlidingTabStrip and ViewPager programatically

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, android-sliding, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am having trouble switching SlidingTabStrip tabs programatically.

I am using SlidingTabStrip in combination with viewpager.

I use

```
mSlidingTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

This moves the viewpager to the selected screen and the corresponding tab is selected.
But if the corresponding tab is not in the view bounds of the screen..
it is not being scrolled into view

This is my SlidingTabStrip.java

```
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {
    /**
     * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
     * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
     */
    public interface TabColorizer {

        /**
         * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
         */
        int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    }

    private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

    private int mTitleOffset;

    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;
    private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

    private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Disable the Scroll Bar
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
     * <p/>
     * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
     * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve
     * similar effects.
     */
    public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
        mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
    }

    public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
        mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
     * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same
     * color.
     */
    public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
     * required to set any {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
     * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
     *
     * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
     */
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
     *
     * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
     * @param textViewId  id of the {@link android.widget.TextView} in the inflated view
     */
    public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
        mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
        mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
     * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
     */
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
            populateTabStrip();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
     * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
     */
    protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }

    private void populateTabStrip() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;

            if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
                // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                        false);
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
            }

            if (tabView == null) {
                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
            }

            if (mDistributeEvenly) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView
                        .getLayoutParams();
                lp.width = 0;
                lp.weight = 1;
            }

            tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
            String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
            if (desc != null) {
                tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
            }

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
            if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                tabView.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
        mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (mViewPager != null) {
            scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
        }
    }

    public void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
            return;
        }

        View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
        if (selectedChild != null) {
            int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

            if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
                // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
                targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
            }
            Timber.i("Scroll "+targetScrollX);
            scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
        }
    }

    private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private int mScrollState;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
//            int count = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
//            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
//                if (position != i) {
//                    ((TextView) mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)).setTextColor(getContext().getResources()
//                            .getColor(R.color.app_text_color_disabled));
//                } else {
//                    ((TextView) selectedTitle).setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor
//                            (R.color.app_text_color));
//                }
//            }
            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                    ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                    : 0;
            scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                scrollToTab(position, 0);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
            }
            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    private class TabClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: check this youtube video it will better help you about ViewPager https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2UZDrYNsX4

Comment: @ZulfiqarAli Thanks for the video.. but my question is not related to actionbar tabs I am Using SlidingTabStrip. If you are not familiar with Sliding tab strip i actually is a Horizontal scrollview with the tabs as the child view so when the child Tab is out of viewable area.. and we change the view pagers current item it is not reflected in the sliding tab itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda found a workaround This is not a legible solution
but what I do is call

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = mainContainer.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                try {
                    mSlidingTabs.scrollToTab(tabPosition,0);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
```

A better solution is welcome.

Comment: Where is the scrollToTab method coming from?

Comment: @tambykojak scrollToTab is a public method available in the SlidingTabLayout custom view I have shared its code above in the question itself.